# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-loader/webpack'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I built React project it gives following error. What can i do to solve this problem.I  use latest react-hot-loader

[Here i have attached error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q94uj.png)

Comment: We can't help you with only error. Please provide details about what you have done so far. Pro tips for a better reception here: (1) put everything readers need in the question itself; (2) use the code formatting tools provided; (3) use succinct titles that describe your problem; (4) refrain from please-help-me pleading

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `node_modules` folder and do `yarn install` again.

```
Go to your project folder and run:
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install or npm install
```